# Fullscreen video that trims from both left and right sides when the screen gets smaller

Tags: html, css

There are a lot of tutorials that shows fullscreen video. But all of them just trims the video from only left or right side when screen gets smaller. The video contains a content in the center and I want to show the content to users every time.

Answer (score 0):

The things you are asking about are called pillar-boxing and letter-boxing. Pillar-boxing chops off the *sides* of the video, so pillar-boxing is used when the video is not tall enough. Letter-boxing is when the *top and bottom* of the video are chopped off, so letter-boxing is used when the video is not wide enough/too tall.

What you want to do is figure out which one your video is using, then increase the height or width to change the type of boxing used, or neutralise the boxing entirely.